# Expectation of chained same probability events

Tags: probability

I am playing with genetic algorithms and I am mutating each chromosome by changing 25% of its genes while random decimal {0,1} is greater than 0.8. This random decimal is generated at least once and it keeps generating after every mutation.

Now I'm trying to calculate what is the expected gene mutation rate for each chromosome, but I am not so good with probabilities and statistics. I understand that expectation would be 5% if the event wasn't recurring.

[attempt to visually describe what am I looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCFbw.png)

What I can derive is 80% probability of 0 mutation, 20% probability of at least 25% mutation and new opportunity to gamble for mutations

Comment: If the random number you pick is greater than 0.8, then you change 25% of the genes  ... and then roll another number to repeat? What exactly happens if the random numbers chosen are 0.9, 0.9, 0.5, for example? After second 0.9 what kind of change will occur? Maybe 25% of the remaining unchanged genes will now be changed?

Comment: 25% of all genes within a given chromosome will change. It means it could be the exact 25% that were changed the first time. If I ignore this then I could simplify the question to what is the expected number of times each chromosome will change at all.

Comment: Are you including the possibility that the second change could revert the first change? In that case the probabilities are affected by the possibility set for individual genes. Otherwise, if you are assuming that reversions are of negligibly low probability then that would make the calculation easier.

Comment: I found my answer by simulating. Average rate of genes changed was 1/(n-1), when the chance of mutation was 1/n

Comment: Can't say I really understand the question but I'm glad you solved it!